# B2G ./build.sh can't find build/envsetup.sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to build FlingOne B2G OS. I downloaded everything fine using the ./config.sh script, but when I tried to use the ./build.sh script I got this returned:

```
 ./build.sh
 setup.sh: line 17: build/envsetup.sh: No such file or directory

 > Build failed! <

 Build with |./build.sh -j1| for better messages
 If all else fails, use |rm -rf objdir-gecko| to clobber gecko and 
 |rm -rf out| to clobber everything else.
```

I tried changing to . /build/envsetup.sh, then cd /build/envsetup.sh, etc. The file is there exactly where it was downloaded, but the build cant find it.

My question is how do I correctly get the script to find the build/envsetup.sh file? Is it something like using the PATH='/build/etc'
or is there some other way?

Comment: To what device did you use ./config.sh?

Comment: the rk30sdk-kk device that's on the wiki here: https://github.com/openflint/openflint.github.io/wiki/Build-Your-Matchstick